# Cannot post questions (confirmed across 3 computers)

Tags: support

I am posting this on behalf of Alec Teal, who has tried to report his inability to post on both blender and the meta as a bug report. It does not appear to be relegated to a specific computer, as he has tried on 3 different ones.

EDIT: (from Alec) Firefox 35.0.0, 37.0 and 33.0 with Adblock+ and Instafox as addons (ABP disabled doesn't change things) on 3 different computers (Linux Mint MATE - if that matters) cannot post.

The error is "An error occurred while submitting the question"

Answer (score 4):

Alec Teal or you should contact Stack Exchange directly.
team@stackexchange.com or by using this form https://blender.stackexchange.com/contact

Let them know your problem, even link to this post.

I would guess that you may have a post block or some other odd problem keeping you from posting to the site. In either event only SE can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox 35.0.0, 37.0 and 33.0 with Adblock+ and Instafox as addons (ABP disabled doesn't change things) on 3 different computers (Linux Mint MATE - if that matters) cannot post.

The error is "An error occurred while submitting the question"

Comment: Got the edit but still cannot post questions

Comment: You should contact SE to get your problem resolved, see [my answer](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/669/2217) for more info.

Comment: I've confirmed your account is not suspended so you should definitely contact SE.